# How to match only the sum of the calculations of the following values in Python

Tags: python

I have such an input file and how to match only the sum of the next ip value calculation and range value and obtaining the first ip value.

Input:

```
Code  Range   Ip
CN    5       16777210
CN    5       16777215
CN    5       16777220
AU    5       16778240
CN    2       16843776
CN    2       16843799
```

(this two values code CN is same )

> but 140(ip) and 2(range)  140 + 2 = 142

So it is not the same calculation the next value 158 
so If the calculation matches the next ip value only the sum of the range values)

If it does not match the calculation of the next IP value, only the original value is needed for the output.

Output: (this output is correct)

```
CN    15      16777210
AU    5       16778240
CN    2       16843776
CN    2       16843799
```

But my python code got the wrong output and it's incorrect as it all calculated the matching code

(Also, the input value of 194000 rows can not read the properly, it does not output all the values, the read file is slow in my code)

Code:

```
stack = []
file = "/Users/kiya/Desktop/input.txt"
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        data[1] = int(data[1])
        if stack and data[0] == stack[-1][0]:
            stack[-1][1] += data[1]
        else:
            stack.append(data)

for i in stack:
    print("{0} {1} {2}".format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

(this is wrong output)

```
CN    15      16777210
AU    5       16778240
CN    4       16843776
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the 3rd column to int and changing the condition to this:

```
if stack and data[0] == stack[-1][0] and sum(stack[-1][1:3]) == data[2]:
```

should produce the result you're looking for:

```
lines = ["CN    5       16777210",
         "CN    5       16777215",
         "CN    5       16777220",
         "AU    5       16778240",
         "CN    2       16843776",
         "CN    2       16843799"]

stack = []
for line in lines: 
    data = [ col for col in line.split(" ") if col != "" ]
    data = [ data[0], int(data[1]), int(data[2]) ]
    if stack and data[0] == stack[-1][0] and sum(stack[-1][1:3]) == data[2]:
        stack[-1][1] += data[1]
    else:
        stack.append(data)

for item in stack:print(item)

['CN', 15, 16777210]
['AU', 5, 16778240]
['CN', 2, 16843776]
['CN', 2, 16843799]
```

Comment: its shows error

    `data = [ data[0], int(data[1]), int(data[2]) ]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: This would mean that your file contains a line that doesn't have 3 values.

Comment: The indexError is not caused by larger number but by a line in the input file that is not formatted as required.  Try printing the lines before the split.